# Flutter: SfDataGrid auto width columns doesn't seem to work as per documentation

Tags: flutter, dart, datatables, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

Having followed the examples here and thoroughly read the [documentation here](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/columns-sizing?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=dart), I simply don't understand why my columns don't show all their content.

See in this screenshot, but the **email** and **phone number** columns are cut off:
[image: Screenshot 2022-07-20 at 10 42 11]

Things I tried to pay attention to:

- Making sure the padding matched on the column and cell builders
- Removing any fixed widths
- Disabling softWrap everywhere I could

Any help to explain why this is happening would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

#### Page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gt_elite/datasource/athlete_data_source.dart';
import 'package:gt_elite/helpers/colors.dart';
import 'package:gt_elite/helpers/constants.dart';
import 'package:gt_elite/helpers/gt_text_style.dart';
import 'package:gt_elite/models/team.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';

class ManagementAdminScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Team team;

  ManagementAdminScreen({@required this.team});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: SfDataGrid(
            source: AthleteDataSource(
              athletes: team.getAthletesForProfile(Profile.athlete),
            ),
            columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.auto,
            columnWidthCalculationRange: ColumnWidthCalculationRange.allRows,
            frozenColumnsCount: 0,
            columns: [
              _buildColumn('avatar', 'profile.athlete'),
              _buildColumn('email', 'email'),
              _buildColumn('phoneNumber', 'phoneNumber'),
              _buildColumn('birthdate', 'birthdate'),
              _buildColumn('height', 'height'),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  GridColumn _buildColumn(String name, String lbl) {
    return GridColumn(
      autoFitPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
      columnName: name,
      label: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          lbl.tr(),
          style: GTTextStyle.subtitle2.copyWith(
            color: GTColors.textGrey,
          ),
          softWrap: false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### AthleteDataSource

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gt_elite/helpers/gt_text_style.dart';
import 'package:gt_elite/helpers/string.dart';
import 'package:gt_elite/models/athlete.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class AthleteDataSource extends DataGridSource {
  final _dateFormatter = DateFormat.yMd();

  AthleteDataSource({List<Athlete> athletes}) {
    dataGridRows = athletes
        .map<DataGridRow>(
          (dataGridRow) => DataGridRow(
            cells: [
              DataGridCell<Athlete>(
                columnName: 'avatar',
                value: dataGridRow,
              ),
              DataGridCell<String>(
                columnName: 'email',
                value: dataGridRow.email,
              ),
              DataGridCell<String>(
                columnName: 'phone',
                value: dataGridRow.phoneNumber,
              ),
              DataGridCell<DateTime>(
                columnName: 'birthdate',
                value: dataGridRow.birthdate,
              ),
              DataGridCell<double>(
                columnName: 'height',
                value: dataGridRow.height,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
        .toList();
  }

  List<DataGridRow> dataGridRows = [];

  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => dataGridRows;

  @override
  bool shouldRecalculateColumnWidths() {
    return true;
  }

  void _launchCaller(String url) async {
    final uri = Uri.parse(url);
    if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
      await launchUrl(uri);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $uri';
    }
  }

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((dataGridCell) {
      // Avatar cell
      if (dataGridCell.columnName == 'avatar') {
        if (dataGridCell.value.getAvatarUrl() != null) {
          return Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: 18,
                ),
                if (dataGridCell.value.getAvatarUrl() != null)
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 30,
                      height: 30,
                      // decoration: getBoxDecoration(),
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                          imageUrl: dataGridCell.value.getAvatarUrl(),
                          placeholder: (context, url) =>
                              CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                              Icon(Icons.error),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                if (dataGridCell.value.getAvatarUrl() == null)
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 30,
                  ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                      child: Text(
                        "${StringHelper.shortName(dataGridCell.value.lastName, nameLimit: 15)}",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: GTTextStyle.subtitle2,
                      ),
                    ),
                    FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                      child: Text(
                        "${StringHelper.shortName(dataGridCell.value.firstName, nameLimit: 15)}",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: GTTextStyle.body,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ]);
        }
      }
      if (dataGridCell.columnName == 'birthdate') {
        if (dataGridCell.value == null) return Container();
        return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Text(
              _dateFormatter.format(dataGridCell.value),
              // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: GTTextStyle.body,
              softWrap: false,
            ));
      }

      if (dataGridCell.columnName == 'phone') {
        if (dataGridCell.value == null) return Container();
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            String phoneNumber = dataGridCell.value;
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll(".", "");
            _launchCaller('tel:${phoneNumber}');
          },
          child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: Text(
                dataGridCell.value.toString(),
                // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: GTTextStyle.body,
                softWrap: false,
              )),
        );
      }

      if (dataGridCell.columnName == 'email') {
        if (dataGridCell.value == null) return Container();
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            String val = dataGridCell.value;
            val = val.replaceAll(" ", "");
            _launchCaller('mailto:${val}');
          },
          child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              // The autoFitPadding and the cell padding value should be same.
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: Text(
                // dataGridCell.value.toString(),
                "123thisisareallylongemail@longemaildomain.com",
                // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: GTTextStyle.body,
                softWrap: false,
              )),
        );
      }

      if (dataGridCell.columnName == 'height') {
        if (dataGridCell.value == null) return Container();
        return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Text(
              dataGridCell.value.toString(),
              // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: GTTextStyle.body,
              softWrap: false,
            ));
      }

      return Container();
    }).toList());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a different text style for the cell widget. By default, the cell width is calculated based on the default text style. To calculate the cell width based on a different TextStyle, just override the **computeHeaderCellWidth** method for the header and the **computeCellWidth** method for the cell and return the super method with the required TextStyle. Please check the following sample and code snippet.

In DataGrid:

```dart
  final CustomColumnSizer _customColumnSizer = CustomColumnSizer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter SfDataGrid'),
      ),
      body: SfDataGrid(
          source: _employeeDataSource,
          columns: getColumns,
          columnSizer: _customColumnSizer,
          columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.auto),
    );
  }
```

```dart
class EmployeeDataSource extends DataGridSource {

…

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter? buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((dataGridCell) {
      return Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          child: Text(
            dataGridCell.value.toString(),
            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            softWrap: false,
          ));
    }).toList());
  }
}
```

In ColumnSizer:

```dart
class CustomColumnSizer extends ColumnSizer {
  @override
  double computeHeaderCellWidth(GridColumn column, TextStyle style) {
    style = const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);

    return super.computeHeaderCellWidth(column, style);
  }

  @override
  double computeCellWidth(GridColumn column, DataGridRow row, Object? cellValue,
      TextStyle textStyle) {
    textStyle = const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);

    return super.computeCellWidth(column, row, cellValue, textStyle);
  }
}
```

Sample Link:  https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/main-621685425

Also, we have already provided examples in our UG documentation. Please go through this,

UG Documentation:  https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/columns-sizing?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=dart#autofit-calculation-based-on-different-textstyle

We hope this helps. Please let us know if you require any further assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used this package, and at first, the result was quite different. But after a little bit, I get a way to alter the width of the Column. I was only able to set maximum and minimum width of the column.
Tip: Make sure to add a key to `SfDataGrid`
Create a class that `extends` `ColumnSizer` and `override` it's `computeCellWidth` method.

```dart
class ColumnSizeController extends ColumnSizer {
  @override
  double computeCellWidth(
    GridColumn column,
    DataGridRow row,
    Object? cellValue,
    TextStyle textStyle,
  ) {
    // I set the property to maximumWidth but you can play more.
    return column.maximumWidth;
  }
}
```

Use this class at `columnSizer` property of `SfDataGrid` class

```dart
     child: SfDataGrid(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.auto,
        columnSizer: ColumnSizeController(),
```

Now set `maximumWidth` and `minimumWidth` properties of each `GridColumn

```dart
          GridColumn(
            maximumWidth: 500,
            minimumWidth: 200,
```

The result is here. (three dots at the end of text are added explicitly)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately that breaks when you are also freezing the first column.  It's also not a fix, more of a workaround to what the package says it should be able to do.  Thank you anyway.

Comment: you might wanna check out the accepted answer in case that helps with your app too.